# Pyschool Quiz--String Concatenation

Tags: python, escaping, string-concatenation, string-literals

Here's the quiz question:

> Adding two strings or making multiple copies of the same string.
>
> Examples:
>
> greetings = "Hello World"
>
> len(greetings) # get the length of string
>
> ```
>  11
> ```
>
> greetings[0] # get the 1st character
>
> ```
>  'H'
> ```
>
> print underline("Good Day")
>
> ```
>  Good Day
>  ________
> ```
>
> # Write a function, given a string of characters, return the string together with '_'s of the same length.

My first attempt was:

```
def underline(title): 
  print title
  print len(title) * '_'
```

...which somewhat passes visually but returns a 'None' value also. (any idea why that is?) So instead I tried:

```
def underline(title): 
  print title, \nlen(title) * '_'
```

...and get an "unexpected character after line continuation character" error. Turning here after Google was less than helpful with this error.

Comment: Mark as answer to the question which gave you solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58782552/android-resource-linking-failed-im-tired-and-i-cant-solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't want to *print* those strings, you want to *return* them.

So create a string that combines them together (separated by a newline character) and return that.

```
def underline(title):
    return title + '\n' + len(title) * '_'
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, knew I was making it harder than it needed to be.

Answer (score 2):

Quote your newline

```
def underline(title): 
    print title, '\n', len(title) * '_'
```

Good point by Jeff (that's why your statement is returning `None`), I was pointing out what's causing this line continuation error.

As the error says, the line continuation character `\` is not expecting any characters after it :)

Comment: Thanks Yuji, I guess every time I've used \n before, it's been within a string by necessity. Thanks for the helping hand.

Comment: Plus one for pointed out the error. (ref: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) or (https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/slash.html)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while attempting one of the practice question in pyschool

Answer:

```
def underline(title):
            return title + '\n' + '_' *l en(title)
```

Comment: Hi Nakul, please be careful with the syntax and abbreviation, it is not clear to me if you intended to refer to "pyschool ans" or "ans" stands for Answer. By the way, the problem of the original poster is the "/" (not wrapped in quotes) that is used to extend statements into multiple lines, it is actually called "continuation character".